# What does settings(inThisBuild(...)) mean in sbt?

Tags: sbt

I just generated an sbt project using scalaxb template:

```sh
sbt new eed3si9n/scalaxb.g8
```

I got this `build.sbt` file:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  enablePlugins(ScalaxbPlugin).
  settings(inThisBuild(List(
    organization  := "com.example",
    scalaVersion  := "2.13.2",
    crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.13.2", "2.12.12")
  ))).
  settings(
    name          := "test-scalaxb",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(dispatch, scalaXml, scalaParser)
  ).
  settings(
    scalaxbDispatchVersion in (Compile, scalaxb) := dispatchV,
    scalaxbPackageName in (Compile, scalaxb)     := "generated"
  )
```

What does the `inThisBuild` within `settings` mean (Line 3)? I usually see it at the root level of the `build.sbt` file, not under `settings`. How is it different from not having `inThisBuild` at all (e.g. `name` and `libraryDependencies` in above file)?

Comment: I am surprised and puzzled to see this as well, especially since it's coming from one of Eugene's own repos. My best guess is that the meaning would be the same if it were at the top level, but I'm not actually sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What does the `inThisBuild` within `settings` mean?

Semantically it means identical to:

```scala
ThisBuild / organization  := "com.example"
ThisBuild / scalaVersion  := "2.13.2"
ThisBuild / crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.13.2", "2.12.12")
```

Today, I recommend using `ThisBuild / organization`. I should probably update my old Giter8 template.

#### Meta details

sbt has a helper function called `inConfig(Compile)(List(setting1, ...))` to `map` over the settings sequence to scope them to `Compile` configuration, which is useful for defining a setting sequence once and reusing it in `Compile`, `Test`, etc.

In 2015, [Dale contributed](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/1989) another helper function called `inThisBuild(List(setting1, ...))`, which similar to `inConfig(Compile)(...)` scopes the list to `ThisBuild` scope. This is due to sbt 0.13 where scoping was written as `organization in ThisBuild` instead of the slash syntax introduced in 2018.

> I usually see it at the root level of the `build.sbt` file, not under `settings`.

Writing at the root level of the `build.sbt` is called *bare style* build.sbt. Semantically writing setting sequence (including `inThisBuild(...)`) using bare style is identical to putting them in `.settings(...)` in the root subproject (the subproject at `file(".")`) of the build. In [2016](https://github.com/eed3si9n/scalaxb.g8/commit/8eeceeb9f69c431a5b784a786e665539992279a1) when I added that line to eed3si9n/scalaxb.g8 I guess I was *more* committed to getting away from the bare style `build.sbt` than I am today, so I refused to write `inThisBuild(...)` directly on `build.sbt` and put it in `.settings(...)` instead.

As mentioned above, I introduced slash syntax in 2018, which warmed me up to using `ThisBuild / scalaVersion` using bare style (and only for `ThisBuild / ...` and `Global / ...` settings) so it would be the same as the shell syntax.

#### Build-wide setting

> How is it different from not having `inThisBuild` at all (e.g. `name` and `libraryDependencies` in above file)?

See [Build-wide settings](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html#Build-wide+settings):

> To factor out common settings across multiple projects, define the settings scoped to `ThisBuild`. The limitation is that the right-hand side needs to be a pure value or settings scoped to `Global` or `ThisBuild`, and there are no default settings scoped to subprojects.

`ThisBuild` is basically a special subproject name that is provided so you can define default settings for your build. When you define one or more subprojects, and when the subproject doesn't define `scalaVersion` it would fallback to `ThisBuild / scalaVersion`.

Answer (score 0):

From the sbt docs:

> The project axis can also be set to ThisBuild, which means the “entire
> build”, so a setting applies to the entire build rather than a single
> project. Build-level settings are often used as a fallback when a
> project doesn’t define a project-specific setting.

the  first  settings applies to all the subprojects in the entire project , whereas the second one applies only to the root project

Comment: So using them simultaneously means all subprojects of only the root project?

Comment: You will usually have one root project and some subprojects. ThisBuild refers to the entire build definition : root plus the other subprojects. And the root settings for sure applies to only root project. For example organization should be accessible in all projects, root and other subprojects. Whereas scalaparser dependency for eg should only be used in root (which points to  the root folder of your project)

Comment: @Helix112 I don't think your answer really addresses the question. The question isn't "what does `inThisBuild` mean?". Rather, the question is, if `inThisBuild` makes it apply to all subprojects, then why nest it inside the `.settings(...)` of the root project, since that certainly makes it _appear_ to apply to the root project only?